# Jquery CKEditor WYSIWYG editor is showing me all buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I'm following the ckeditor example from [here](http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor_for_jQuery) where I add the script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
```

and call `.ckeditor()` on the appropriate class `.editor`

```
$( 'textarea.editor' ).ckeditor();
```

This shows me a full editor with every button under the sun.

**How can I customize which buttons I want to appear?**

Answer (score 0):

check config.js file of editor

You need to make custom group of toolbars which u want to show.

check here

http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Setting_Configurations

Answer (score 0):

in config.js you can define your toolbars, or modify the default toolbars. It looks like this:

```
config.toolbar_Basic = [
    ['Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', '-','About']
];
```

see http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Toolbar for more information